# Import OpenAPI Spec Generated Types

Tags: typescript, axios, openapi-generator

I am attempting to import types generated by [`openapi-client-axios`](https://github.com/anttiviljami/openapi-client-axios/blob/master/DOCS.md#typegen) into a Typescript file. The high-level setup is that I have a backend web service from which an `api.json` file is generated creating an OpenAPI specification for the provided rest service. Then, I'm trying to use that file to create a client object which I can use to call that service in the front-end Typescript. The first part of this (web service -> api.json file) works without issue. I am also able to successfully run:

```
typegen api.json > proto.d.ts
```

This results in a file, `proto.d.ts` that contains the client typing definition. I place this file at `src/types/proto.d.ts` in my project, but run into trouble when trying to import it into the code where I actually need it. That file is `src/rigging/api.ts` and looks like this:

```
import OpenAPIClientAxios from 'openapi-client-axios';
import { RestClient } from '@types';  // Error occurs here
// These also don't work
// import { RestClient } from './types/proto'
// import { RestClient } from 'proto'
// import { RestClient } from './types/proto.d.ts'
// import { RestClient } from 'proto.d.ts'
// import { RestClient } from '@types/proto'
// ... etc.

const api = new OpenAPIClientAxios({ definition: 'http://localhost:8000/openapi.json' });
const MyRestApi = api.getClient<RestClient>();

export default MyRestApi;
```

The error that occurs on the `import { RestClient } ...` line seems obvious enough:

> TS2307: Cannot find module '@types' or its corresponding type declarations.

What isn't obvious to me is how to fix this. I've tried renaming the `proto.d.ts` file to `index.d.ts` and moved it around, but I can't seem to get it to be properly loaded. I've tried to figure out how Typescript goes about loading definition files but cannot find an example of this sort of generated type definition file being loaded.

There is plenty I don't understand yet about Typescript, axios and Vue (the framework I'm using), but it seems to me this importation is the isolated issue I'm stuck on now. The `@` notation seems to be what articles online suggest, but neither it nor a dot notation (i.e. `./types/proto.d.ts`) seem to work, resulting in one of a handful of other errors in the same vein (can't find or import the module, wrong extension, etc.). I'd love a concise explanation of how Typescript goes about finding this object, or an explanation of where I've gone wrong structuring this. Currently, my file structure is:

```
src/
|- main.ts
|- App.vue
|- ...
|- rigging/
|  |- api.ts
|
|- types/
   |- proto.d.ts
```

At the root (above `src`) I also have `vue.config.js` and `tsconfig.json`, which I understand might impact this (i.e. maybe I have my `typeRoots` wrong? It's currently set to `[ "./types" ]`) but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

In case it's useful, this is the generated `proto.d.ts` file:

```
import {
  OpenAPIClient,
  Parameters,
  // UnknownParamsObject,
  OperationResponse,
  AxiosRequestConfig,
} from 'openapi-client-axios';

declare namespace Components {
  namespace Schemas {
    export interface Codex {
      id: number; // uint64
      name: string;
    }
  }
}
declare namespace Paths {
  namespace RestApiGetCodex {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
    namespace Parameters {
      export type Id = number; // uint64
    }
    export interface PathParameters {
      id: Parameters.Id; // uint64
    }
    namespace Responses {
      export type $200 = Components.Schemas.Codex;
    }
  }
}

export interface OperationMethods {
  /**
   * rest_api_get_codex
   */
  'rest_api_get_codex'(
    parameters?: Parameters<Paths.RestApiGetCodex.PathParameters>,
    data?: any,
    config?: AxiosRequestConfig
  ): OperationResponse<Paths.RestApiGetCodex.Responses.$200>
}

export interface PathsDictionary {
  ['/codex/{id}']: {
    /**
     * rest_api_get_codex
     */
    'get'(
      parameters?: Parameters<Paths.RestApiGetCodex.PathParameters>,
      data?: any,
      config?: AxiosRequestConfig
    ): OperationResponse<Paths.RestApiGetCodex.Responses.$200>
  }
}

export type RestClient = OpenAPIClient<OperationMethods, PathsDictionary>
```

Comment: `import {} from "proto";`

Comment: `TS2307: Cannot find module 'proto' or its corresponding type declarations.` is what results there.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding `typeRoots`. That specifies where to find type declarations that correspond to the JavaScript contained in 3rd party packages. If your are just trying to import types from a file that doesn't correspond to some 3rd party JavaScript, you should not customize `typeRoots` but rather just import directly from the file containing your types.

Comment: Ok, so what does that look like? I realized that `typeRoots` may just refer to third party libraries in my dependency graph and therefore be a red herring, but it still is not importing a straight file - I think because the extension is not what it expects? I don't really know, except that I get the errors noted when I attempt to import it. `import ... './types/proto.d.ts'` doesn't work, and I'm not clear what will.

Comment: Import without the `.d.ts` extension

Comment: The import statement fails with or without the `.d.ts` extension, with or without relative versus `@` pathing. The TS2307 error persistently arises; I'm fairly convinced some plumbing is missing somewhere (but what?) or something like (though it looks like not actually) `typeRoots` is set incorrectly. I've updated the question with some of the variants I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the solution was relatively easy:

```
import OpenAPIClientAxios from 'openapi-client-axios';
import { RestClient } from '@types/proto.d';  // Only drop the 'ts' part of the extension
```

The `typeRoots` parameter in the `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
    "typeRoots": [
      "./src/types"
    ],
```

This enables the `@` to refer to the root of the source directory. However, it is quite literal in that the import only drops the `.ts` part of the file name, so you have to import it keeping the `.d` part; hence `from proto.d`. An alternative is to drop the `.d` from the name on the filesystem itself, though that breaks with the definition file convention.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using [openapi-generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators)

Useful generators for Frontend:

- `typescript-axios`
- `typescript-fetch`

I used `typescript-fetch` with `React` on 2 large projects and it works like magic.

Generating example:

```sh
// cli or package.json script

npx @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i ./api.json -g typescript-axios -o ./generated/api/ --additional-properties=typescriptThreePlus=true
```

[CLI](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/bin/utils/openapi-generator-cli.sh) executable version with latest build

Comment: This, I'm afraid, doesn't actually answer the question. I am using the openapi-generator for Axios to create the above listed definition file. But this doesn't solve my problem of *where to put it*. The 'like magic' part is actually the part getting in the way - magic is hard to explain, and therefore hard to modify.

Comment: I admit, this is not the answer to the problem. The problem is sometimes the tool you use. This is my advice based on great results and simplicity of integration into any frontend framework.

Comment: I understand; the issue is that the question is being asked in a larger context. For hardened production-ready cicd pipelines 'like magic' is often insufficient; knowing how the plumbing works is critical.